# Is there a way to retrieve realtime firebase map as a linkedhashmap or at least maintain the order it is saved in

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I have a map of string boolean pairs saved on firebase realtime database and was wondering if there is a way to retrieve it in kotlin as a linkedhashmap such that the original order remains in place.

I have tried typecasting to a linkedhashmap and got an error that hashmap cannot be typecasted to linked hashmap, I then tried calling the linkedhashmap constructor method with the parameter being the data from the database as a hashmap but that does not maintain the order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties in JSON are by definition not in any specific order.

While you *can* retrieve data from Firebase in a specific order, by calling one of its `orderBy...` operations, that order will be lost when you call `.value` in the `DataSnapshot` as [`DataSnapshot.value`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getValue()) returns a `Map`, which is unordered again.

If you want to retrieve the nodes in a specific order:

1. [Call `orderBy...`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sort_data) to get the nodes in a specific order.
2. [Loop over the `children`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#kotlin+ktx_2) of the snapshot you get back to process them in order, and only call `value` on each specific child node.